# how to use onclick in LaravelCollective

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I am using Laravel Collective form. I want to use onclick analytic.js but the browser shows me an error. here is the code

```
<div class="field-name">
{{--<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'your name', :onclick => "ga('send','event', 'form-lp-input', 'step3-name', '', 0);" %>--}}
{!!Form::text('name','yes',null,['placeholder'=>'yourname','onclick'=>'ga('send', 'event', 'form-lp-input', 'step2-zip',
 '', 0);'])!!}
</div>
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oAWm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- `Form::text()` only uses **3** parameters, you are passing **4**:

```
public static function text($name, $value = null, $options = array())
```

- You have to escape your single-quoted javscript string or use double-quotes:

try this:

```
{!!Form::text('name', 'yes', ['placeholder' => 'yourname', 'onclick' => 'ga("send", "event", "form-lp-input", "step2-zip","", 0);'])!!}
```

Comment: this solved my problem but can you give me some more explanation about the \ you used?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can escape the single-quoted javascript or use double-quotes. The problem is you are using a single-quoted string so you cant use another single-quote inside without breaking it. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/9193055).

Answer (score 0):

I see I'm answering a bit late :) but still, maybe this solution will help someone...

To escape quotes you can use `\Illuminate\Support\HtmlString` [class](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/HtmlString.html) as following:

```
{!! Form::text('name', 'yes', ['placeholder' => 'yourname', 'onclick' => (new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString("ga('send', 'event', 'form-lp-input', 'step2-zip', '', 0)"))]) !!}
```